# How to attach events, only once, to elements created in the future in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I attach events to elements created in the future in jQuery, only once?

I understand that .live() works in attaching events for elements created in the future, but will attach events multiple times like .bind() does. But I need to attach the event only once.

**EXAMPLE:**

For my case

http://jsfiddle.net/ppTqp/1/  -> Should alert "Live from test" only once. With .live method it alerts twice.

Comment: Btw `.live()` is kind-of deprecated... in favor of `.delegate()` and `.on()`...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: You are partially right: `.live()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()`, but `.delegate()` is (and was) the suggested solution instead of `.live()` for older versions of jQuery. So, for new versions (>1.7) choose `.on()`, for older ones try to use `.delegate()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Apparently you want that an event handler is only bound once when you make several calls to `live`, `delegate` or `on`.

In this case you'd have to unbind the event handler first. You can use namespaces to only unbind the specific event handler:

```
$(document).off('click.namespace').on('click.namespace', selector, function() {

});
```

In case of `live`, you have to call `die`:

```
$(...).die('click').live(...)
```

---

I assume the event handler is bound to several elements. Due to the nature of `live`, `delegate` or `on` (for that matter), you cannot just "unbind" the event handler when it was executed for one element, as it won't be fired for any other element anymore. Instead, uou have to keep track for which element it was fired.

Example:

```
$(document).on('click', selector, function() {
    if(!$(this).data('fired')) {
        $(this).data('fired', true);
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```

The other solution would be to use `.one()` and bind the event handler whenever you create new elements.

---

Regarding your terminology:

You cannot *attach events*, but event *handlers*. `bind` does not attach events or event handlers multiple times, just once, but once it is bound, it will always fire for a certain event. If you want to an event handler to be called only once, you have to unbind it after it was called.

Comment: This will trigger events only once. But I want to attach event handlers only once. The `// do your stuff` part should execute every time I click BUT should not execute twice if the whole block `on` was run twice in the same DOM. Bind executes the attach even twice if the bind block is run twice.

Comment: @GeekTantra: Oh, then I misunderstood your question and rolled back the changes I made. I think you didn't express your problem clearly enough. `one` also binds an event handlers twice if called twice afaik, but executes the handler only once... this was not a good example then...

Comment: Yes that was what I was referring to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ppTqp/1/ -> Should alert "Live from test" only once. With .live method it alerts twice. Can you give an example which mapst fo my case?

Comment: As I said, you'd have to unbind the event handler before. In this, case, the second call to `live` should be `$(...).die('click').live(...)`.

Comment: The only difference between one and this method would be the last call would overwrite the previous call in this way. Anyways it works for my case. Thanks a lot. Please edit your answer accordingly so that I can check it as correct.

Comment: @GeekTantra: No, `one` does not overwrite. It binds an event handler which is only executed once. That is the difference and that is actually not what you want so it is confusing that you mention it. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ppTqp/2/

Comment: Yup I understood that. Had a bit of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as:

```
$("#foo").one("click", function() {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

to execute at most once per element